# [['19'], ['19', '21']] convert this to [19,19,21] in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I remove the `list` inside list(Double Square Brackets) and make it as list of type integer.

I tried choosing one element at a time:

```
enter code here
x = [['19'], ['19', '21']]
x = (int(x) for x in x)
```

But instead it results in `<generator object>`.

Comment: You want to _flatten a nested list_.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the lists together you will get your desired result like:

#### Code:

```
sum(x, [])
```

#### Test Code:

```
x = [['19'], ['19', '21']]

print(sum(x, []))
```

#### Results:

```
['19', '19', '21']
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
final_list = [i for sub_list in x for i in sub_list]
```